# ¿Por qué no funciona mi botón que calcula descuentos?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Total a pagar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <FIELDSET><legend>SUPER DESCUENTOS</legend><center>
    <label>PRECIO</label>
    <input type="text" name="precio"><br><br>
    <label>DESCUENTO</label>
    <input type="text" name="descuento"><br><br>
    <center><input type="button" name="resultado" id="resultado" value="TOTAL" onclick="resultado();"></center>
    <label>El costo total es de:</label>
            </center></FIELDSET>

<center><div id="resultado"></div></center><!--se abre y cierra el contenedor-->
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var precio=parseInt(document.getElementById('precio').value);
        var descuento=parseInt(document.getElementById('descuento').value);
        var resultado=true;

     function resultado(){
        var resultado=(precio()*descuento()/100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para añadir más detalles: ¿qué hace el código que compartes? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Cuál es el resultado que recibes? ¿Te da algún error? Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro no son de ayuda a otros usuarios. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varios errores. En el html:

1. Los input no tienen id. Para utilizar desde javascript 'getElementById', el elemento al que haces referencia debe tener uno.
2. Tienes dos elementos con el mismo id. El botón y el div de resultado, ambos tienen el id = 'resultado'. Para el ejemplo cambiamos el id del botón por 'btnresultado', aunque tu luego puedes cambiar el que quieras. Lo importante es que no pueden haber dos elementos con el mismo id ya que debería ser únicos.

En cuanto al javascript:

1. Esto no es un error, pero en este caso creo que no debería estar así. Las variables 'precio' y 'descuento' las declaras como globales y en este contexto deberían declararse dentro de la función.
2. La variable 'resultado' que también declaras como global no tiene ningún sentido.
3. Cuando calculas el resultado, utilizas la variables 'precio' y 'descuento' como funciones(les añades () al final). Esto no es correcto ya que son variables.
4. No estas pintando el resultado por pantalla.

Y por último, si lo que quieres calcular es el precio final, el cálculo que haces es incorrecto, ya que estás calculando el descuento. Para calcular el precio final, debes restarle a 'precio' el 'resultado'.

```js
     function resultado(){
            var precio=parseInt(document.getElementById('precio').value);
            var descuento=parseInt(document.getElementById('descuento').value);
            var resultado=(precio*descuento)/100;
           
           document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = precio - resultado;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Total a pagar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <FIELDSET><legend>SUPER DESCUENTOS</legend><center>
        <label>PRECIO</label>
        <input id="precio" type="text" name="precio"><br><br>
        <label>DESCUENTO</label>
        <input id="descuento" type="text" name="descuento"><br><br>
        <center><input type="button" name="resultado" id="btnresultado" value="TOTAL" onclick="resultado();"></center>
        <label>El costo total es de:</label>
                </center></FIELDSET>
    
    <center><div id="resultado"></div></center><!--se abre y cierra el contenedor-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio :)